# Multiple Tasks as part of custom List Workflow - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have a custom list (Employees) and a task list (Applications) 
The Employees list has a field that takes in multiple selections from the Applications list.
The Applications list has different tasks assigned to it like (emailing a certain user, etc)
How do I make it so that when a new item is created in the Employees list that all the Application tasks selected for the new employee is kicked off? There could be 1 or more applications.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think I would tend to change the relation of the list. Right now you relate from Employees to Applications, leading to a column that refers to several entries in a different list. As I don't know how to handle that, I would turn that around and point the Application list to the Employee. Like that you could just select all entries in the Application list containing a reference to the Employee.

I am unsure however, how you could have a reference to tasks (or Application) of an Employee that has not yet been created..

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you create SharePoint list trigger (Event receiver) that when you add new record in employee list, this option add to mutiple seclection list in application.

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-in-SharePoint-2013-and-SharePoint-2010